# MVC controller name appears twice in URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, controller, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an image link extension that I am using to navigate to the same view with some calculations. Once the user chooses a value from a dropdown list and clicks the link, I need to navigate to the same view and pass the value of their selection. Everything is working, except for the controller name I am passing to is being hit twice. I cannot seem to wrap my head around why this is happening.

Consider two views, one is Project and another one is ProjectRoles. First I am navigating to the ProjectRoles page from Project View via an Action link. After that one more image link is there in the ProjectRoles view, Now If I click it then the url should pass a parameter with help of querystring, but the controller name comes twice. Where I did go wrong? Or Is it not possible in MVC?

My project view code:

```
protected string LinkButtonAddPerson(string action, string controllerName, string actionName, long id, long createUser, string status,int projectId)
{
        string link = string.Empty;

        // Controller Name: ProjectRolesController     Action: AddEditProjectRoles
        string querystring = "<a href='../" + controllerName + "/" + actionName + "/?id=" + id + "&status=###status"+ "&projectId="+ projectId + "&veryfirstTime=Y'  ><img id='###ahrefID' src='../../Content/Images/###image'></a>";

        link = querystring.Replace("###status", Constants.Status.Pending).Replace("###image", "addperson.png").Replace("###ahrefID", "addperson");
        //link = querystring.Replace("###status", "P").Replace("###image", "edit.png").Replace("###ahrefID", "edit");
        return link;
 }
```

And ImageLinke button in ProjectRoles:

```
protected string LinkButton(string action, string controllerName, string actionName, long id, long 
createUser, string status, string firstcall="N")
{
     string link = string.Empty;
     string querystring = "";

     // Controller Name: ProjectRolesController     Action: AddEditProjectRoles
    querystring = "<a href='../" + controllerName + "/" + actionName + "/?id=" + id + "&status=###status'><img id='###ahrefID' src='../../Content/Images/###image'></a>";

    link = querystring.Replace("###status", Constants.Status.Pending).Replace("###image", "edit.png").Replace("###ahrefID", "edit");

    return link;
}
```

And my AddEditProjectRoles:

```
 public ActionResult AddEditProjectRoles(int? Id, string status,int projectId, string veryfirstTime="N")
 {
     ... 
     ...
     ...
     // Based on the parameter value, fetching the details. 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, avoid using `../../` instead use `~/`

Second, use `Url.Action` to generate the url

```
var url = Url.Action(actionName, controllerName, new { id = id });
```

then use it as href

```
querystring = $"<a href='{url}" + "&status=###status'><img id='###ahrefID' src='~/Content/Images/###image'></a>";
```